# Why star rating value not getting?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get star rating value for products in PHP-Laravel. But value not getting in print_r value. When i submit with giving star rating, the value rating gives value twice in URL, one is real value and other is 0, but in print_r value give only 0. Any way to get the value for name attribute.

[image]

I am using [this library](https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/tree/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3) for star rating. Form code:

```
<form action="{{action('products_controller@product_review')}}">
            <span>
              <input name="username" type="text" placeholder="Your Name"/>

              <input name="useremail" type="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
            </span>
            <textarea name="" ></textarea>

              <input name="rating" type="text" class="rating-kv" min=0 max=5 step=0.2 data-size="sm">

              <br>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Controller code:

```
public function product_review(Request $req)

      {
          $data = $req -> all();

          echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;

      }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have the `method` attribute to your `<form>`?

Comment: For some reason you have `rating` twice in the URL. The last one is 0, so you're getting expected output atm as the last one will stick.

Comment: PHP simply overwrites parameters with the same name (unless [ and ] are used in the name attribute) - but there is no apparent reason here why the form you have shown would produce this form data set in the first place. Your problem is not reproducible with what you have shown.

Comment: how to get solution of it @04FS

Comment: i have added method, @Akintunde-Rotimi

Comment: any idea for getting solution? @Jonnix

Comment: @NayeemHyderRiddhi Sure, find out why it's there twice and stop it.

Comment: @Jonnix, here is the rating js, https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/blob/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3/js/star-rating.js

Comment: Show us how you are initializing this script then. It seems to make some modifications to the form, so you might simply not be using it correctly.

Comment: @04FS whole blade scripts or js scripts?

Comment: The JS part, that appears to be manipulating the form.

Comment: @04FS, https://github.com/glix/j-plugin/blob/master/Simple-jQuery-Star-Rating-System-For-Bootstrap-3/js/star-rating.js    js part

Comment: I meant you should show us how you are _using_ this library, your JS code that initializes the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<input  type="text" class="rating-kv" id ="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.2 data-size="sm">
<input  type ="hidden" name ="rating" id ="ratingValue" >
```

in jquery part add

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $(".rating-kv").rating();
        $('body').on("change","#rating",function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var rating = $(".rating-kv").val();
            $("#ratingValue").val(rating);
        });
    });
</script>
```